# code take more than 10 minutes to be executed

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code to import text file tab delimiter, and use for loop for more than one million row, to modify some range("AF") with caller ID, but the problem it takes more than 10 minutes to finish and open the excel with the result.
So any suggestion to speed up the following code,

```vb
Public Function txtimport() As Integer
    Dim b1 As Workbook, s As String, J As Long
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    s = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If s = "False" Then
        txtimport = 1
        GoTo Nofile
    Else
        txtimport = 0
    End If
    Close #1
    Open s For Input As #1
    J = 1
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=s, Origin:= _
            437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
            , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), _
            Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2), Array(5, 2), Array(6, 2), Array(7, 2), Array(8, 2), Array(9, 2), _
            Array(10, 2), Array(11, 2), Array(12, 2), Array(13, 2), Array(14, 2), Array(15, 2), Array( _
            16, 2), Array(17, 2), Array(18, 2), Array(19, 2), Array(20, 2), Array(21, 2), Array(22, 2), _
            Array(23, 2), Array(24, 2), Array(25, 2), Array(26, 2), Array(27, 2), Array(28, 2), Array( _
            29, 2), Array(30, 2), Array(31, 2), Array(32, 2), Array(33, 2), Array(34, 2), Array(35, 2), _
            Array(36, 2), Array(37, 2), Array(38, 2), Array(39, 2), Array(40, 2), Array(41, 2), Array( _
            42, 2), Array(43, 2), Array(44, 2), Array(45, 2), Array(46, 2), Array(47, 2)), _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Close #1
    Nofile:
End Function

Sub caller_id()
    Dim caller_id As String
    Dim parent_id, child_id As Long
    Dim parent As Range
    Dim LastRow, r, x As Long
    LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Columns("AF:AF").NumberFormat = "@"
    
    For r = 2 To LastRow
         If Range("AF" & r).Value <> "" And Range("C" & r) <> "0" Then
             caller_id = Range("AF" & r).Value
             child_id = Range("C" & r).Value
             Set parent = Range("B:B").Find(child_id)
             If parent Is Nothing Then
             Else
                 x = parent.Row
                 Range("AF" & x).Value = caller_id
             End If
        End If
    Next r
    
End Sub
    
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim y As Integer
    y = txtimport
    If y = 0 Then
        Call caller_id
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It would helpf if you show us a small subset of your data: as it is imported and the expected result.

Comment: You run the `Find` method 1 million times? No wonder it takes 10 minutes. Work with arrays instead of ranges (google there are tutorials how to do that) and using `WorksheetFunction.Match` on the array instead of `Find` on a range might speed it up a bit but in the end imagine that 1 million times is a lot and will take time. I mean 10 minutes for 1 million means 0.0006 seconds per iteration. That is not that slow. What takes your time is the huge amount of data.

Comment: Here is a good article about speeding up loops using something other than `Find()`: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

Comment: Just switching to Match against the worksheet (and not against an array, which is not as fast) would be much faster (assuming you want an exact and not partial match).  Also if you're working on performance it's good to give us some idea of which part of your code is taking the most time.  Eg `txtimport` takes how long vs. `caller_id` ?

Comment: How many of the million rows have `Range("AF" & r).Value <> "" And Range("C" & r) <> "0"`

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, here is a sample for the file which I used in import (uploaded on wetransfer, also txtimport take around 10 or 20 seconds, but caller_id take 10 minutes

Comment: we.tl/t-BxugecvEVD